# Contents of File Written in Java Disappears in Unix

Tags: java, unix

I have a Java code that writes to a file after selecting which rows to process. The problem is that by the end of the execution, the contents of the file being written on completely disappears. The weird thing is that the code works properly on Windows but doesn't on Unix. One other thing is that when only one entry is selected, the code works as it should but when more than one entry is selected, it just fails.

No other operation is performed on this file while it is being written on.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Show us some code. Guessing at your problem is a waste of our time and yours.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons why this happens:

1. You forgot to close the file. Symptom: The file exists but it has length 0.
2. You're using `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` and forgot to flush it.
3. Someone deleted the file while you were writing it.

The latter is a security feature: As long as you keep the file open, you can read and write it but no one else can access it.